# Is it effective to prevent SQL injection by doubling a single quote using Postgres 11?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, security, sql-injection

Is it fully effective when using Postgres 11 in Node.js backend?
I've tested the code with a lot of cheatsheets and everything was fine.

PostgreSQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO test(a, b) VALUES ('${Utils.esc(a)}', '${Utils.esc(b)}')
```

Code to prevent SQL Injection:

```
esc: (str) => {
    return str.toString().replace(/(['])/g, "'$1");
},
```

Preliminary tests didn't show me any susceptibility, but maybe one of you knows more.

Comment: No.  It is not sufficient.  Use parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've tested the code with a lot of cheatsheets and everything was fine. Why?

Comment: . . You'd better learn quickly that *your* testing does not define security on a system.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have just been instructed to show that it is as you say it is. I'd rather use the parameters.